# Oracle sqldeveloper with Openjdk8

Tags: java, oracle-sqldeveloper

How to integrate openjdk 8 with sql developer.  When I try to integrate its not working me

Error in sql developer is

Warning:  could not install some modules

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking. See the How to Ask page for help clarifying this question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We don't officially support the openjdk, what we're expecting at run time is the Oracle JDK, version 8 specifically.

We're targeting support for 11/12 later this year.

Comment: Thanks for your info